# Error in thenComparing is not applicable for the arguments Comparator<..DTO>

Tags: java, comparator

So i'm having an error in the thenComparing line, i don't know what's happening. Can anyone helping me?

```
List<CognodataEstadoSolicitudesDTO> solicitudes 
else if ("columnaFechaSolicitud".equals(orderBy)) {
                    solicitudes = solicitudes.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(t -> {
                        Date fecha = null;
                        try {
                            fecha= ((CognodataEstadoSolicitudesDTO) t).getFechaSolicitudToDate();
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                                LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                        }
                        return fecha;
                    }).thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(CognodataEstadoSolicitudesDTO::getIdSolicitud))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[image]

Comment: Please [do not post error messages in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/7525132). Images are inferior to text, because they cannot be searched, copy pasted, accessed by screen readers and many more.

Comment: How is `solicitudes` defined? That you need a cast (`(CognodataEstadoSolicitudesDTO) t`) in the first comparator hints at a problem with the generic type of `solicitudes`

Comment: List<CognodataEstadoSolicitudesDTO> solicitudes @ThomasKläger

Comment: Btw, why don't you just use `thenComparing(CognodataEstadoSolicitudesDTO::getIdSolicitud)`?

Comment: I have the same error if i do this

Comment: As Thomas Kläger already pointed out, that cast `(CognodataEstadoSolicitudesDTO) t` implies that the comparator created via `Comparator.comparing(...)` already is broken. It could be another error that's preventing the compiler to correctly infer the type though. Could you try `Comparator.comparing((CognodataEstadoSolicitudesDTO t) -> ...)`, i.e. mention the type already in the lambda? If there's an issue with type inference on the stream the error should then shift to `comparing(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the compiler not being able to correctly infer the generic type across multiple levels (lambda, comparator and stream) and including bounds (basically 2 nested `? super T`) so you need to help it out by stating the type in the lambda:

```
 solicitudes.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing((CognodataEstadoSolicitudesDTO t) - { ... })
               .thenComparing(CognodataEstadoSolicitudesDTO::getIdSolicitud))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here you're defining the key extractor to be a `Function<CognodataEstadoSolicitudesDTO , ?>` and thus the compiler knows `comparing(Function<CognodataEstadoSolicitudesDTO , ?> keyExtractor)` will be returning a `Comparator<CognodataEstadoSolicitudesDTO>`.

Answer (score 1):

Using lambda in the first `Comparator.comparing` seems to be redundant as well as reassigning the list after sorting to the same `solicitudes` variable.

It may be better to use method [`List::sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) accepting a comparator and handle possible nulls using [`Comparator::nullsLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-)

```java
solicitudes.sort(
    Comparator.comparing(
        CognodataEstadoSolicitudesDTO::getFechaSolicitudToDate, 
        Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())
    )
    .thenComparing(CognodataEstadoSolicitudesDTO::getIdSolicitud)
);
```

However, if it is really needed to use the lambda as mentioned in the initial code, the type of objects being compared has to be specified for the lambda parameter and it is still needed to handle `null` returned in case of `ParseException`:

```java
solicitudes.sort(
        Comparator.comparing((CognodataEstadoSolicitudesDTO t) -> {
            Date fecha = null;
            try {
                fecha= t.getFechaSolicitudToDate();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage());
            }
            return fecha;
        }, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())
        )
        .thenComparing(CognodataEstadoSolicitudesDTO::getIdSolicitud)
);
```